# Is there a way to check for obsolete clippy allowances?

Tags: rust, rust-clippy

Sometimes you want to suppress a clippy warning for the time being and you let clippy ignore a specific rule for a specific code block by adding lines like the following:

```
#[allow(dead_code)]
```

But as the project continues, it can actually happen that you remove the problem, without actually removing the allowing of the clippy lint. So is there a way to check for allowed clippy warnings that are actually not being used anymore? So in this example I'd like to be informed when I `#[allow(dead_code)]` but there is actually no dead code to be found in the given code block.

Comment: Why even `allow(dead_code)` at all? Why not just keep it as a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unstable feature (currently only usable using the nightly Rust compiler) [`lint_reasons`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2383-lint-reasons.html#expect-lint-attribute) includes the ability to use `expect(` instead of `allow(`, which allows the lint but warns if the lint is *not* detected.

```rust
#![feature(lint_reasons)]

#[expect(dead_code)]
fn foo() {}

fn main() {
    foo();
}
```

Output:

```rust
warning: this lint expectation is unfulfilled
 --> src/main.rs:3:10
  |
3 | #[expect(dead_code)]
  |          ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unfulfilled_lint_expectations)]` on by default
```

[There is no current schedule for this to make it to stable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54503#issuecomment-1245805442) but at least people want to see it and there's an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try prefixing unused functions/variables/etc. with a `_` (the compiler will also mention this.) if you do not want the warnings to appear. If you remove the any of the temporary/dead code containing the prefix, you won't have to worry about `#![allow(dead_code)]`.